# How to group then count groups where a numeric column is within a particular range?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Basically I want to count the number of groups where a column is within a particular range.

Example:

```
DATA:
COL1:           COL2:
CC2SYS_LOAD     2239
CC2SYS_LOAD     2307
CC2SYS_LOAD     2316
CC2SYS_LOAD     7164
CC2SYS_LOAD     7169
CC2SYS_LOAD     7179
```

I need it to return a count of 2 because there are 2 groups of 3 records where the value of COL2 falls with 900 of each other.

There could be 100s or none.

Comment: what if the values of three different rows were (1000, 1899, 2798)? Would they count as being under the same group?

Comment: Are you looking for rows with 900 of each other, where there is an implied order of col2?

Comment: @Boneist That question was not asked.. I don't think so though. I'll have to ask the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    sum(flag) + 1
from (
    select
        case when col2 - lag(col2,1,col2) over (order by col2) > 900 then 1 end flag
    from your_table
) t
```

flag (built using window function `lag`) marks the starting of next group.